# How do I make ASP.NET MVC 3 render objects with complex types in the auto-generated views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have model classes that have as properties items of complex types (i.e., other model classes).  How can I make it so when I automatically generate views from Visual Studio, those classes (that are included in the top-level class) are displayed appropriately?

Basically, how do I update http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html to ASP.NET MVC 3?

TIA,
Benjy

Comment: Yes, you're correct, thanks - I just missed that part.  If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it correct...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking to upgrade to the razor syntax? Otherwise it should still work in mvc 3. Just place your the code in his example in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.ascx

Answer (score 4):

Come on, make a little effort yourself and tell what difficulties you have encountered! Otherwise how do you expect to learn something?

`Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model SampleModel
<h3>Details</h3>
<fieldset style="padding: 1em; margin: 0; border: solid 1px #999;">
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</fieldset>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</p>
```

---

`Views/Home/Edit.cshtml`:

```
@model SampleModel
<h3>Edit</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <fieldset style="padding: 1em; margin: 0; border: solid 1px #999;">
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Broken stuff:")
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <input type="submit" value="  Submit  " />
    </fieldset>
}
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index")</p>
```

---

`Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.cshtml`:

```
@model object
@if (Model == null) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText
} 
else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} 
else 
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
        {
            @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
        }
        else 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;">
                        @prop.GetDisplayName()
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </table>
}
```

---

`Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml`:

```
@model object
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} 
else 
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
        {
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
        } 
        else 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
                        @(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "")
                        @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: This seems to introduce a bug in which viewmodel properties whose names match `ViewBag` or `ViewData` properties are overridden. For example, a property called `Title` will be overriden by the page title.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a view model with a property that returns a list of objects such as

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

you then wish to generate a view that uses this model.  Here is your action method

```
public ViewResult Edit(int productId)
{
   Product product = contextDB.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);

   return View("Edit", product);
}
```

The generated code will look something like this (incomplete)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MyViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId)
        </div>

    ...
    <fieldset>
}
```

The generated code will NOT include any code for the List property by default.   The Razor view engine code generator only goes as deep as the properties of the model.   You can write code that accesses the Details list in the view but it must be custom code.

Comment: How do I write that code to display the entire property tree including all descendants?

Comment: You would have to iterate through all of the properties and embedded objects with their own properties or lists of embedded objects and their properties inside of the view.  If you wish to embed a model within a model, you might want to make the embedded model the model for a partial view.   I would definitely NOT put a lot of C# code in the view to iterate through an embedded model.